# Add nullable foreign key in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Referencing to Rails 4.2 [add_foreign_key](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#foreign-key-support) support:

```
    # add a foreign key to `articles.author_id` referencing `authors.id`
    add_foreign_key :articles, :authors
```

How to create a nullable foreign key constraint, to allow the situation, where `articles.author_id` can be sometimes null?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing in the guide that implies `add_foreign_key` would make the corresponding foreign field "NOT NULL" or required. `add_foreign_key` simply adds a foreign key constraint whether the field is required or not (in your case `author_id` in `articles`).

Did you get an error when you tried this in your migration?

Here's the SQL that it would generate:

```
ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD CONSTRAINT articles_author_id_fk FOREIGN KEY ("author_id") REFERENCES "authors" ("id")
```

SO, if in your original migration of `articles`, `author_id` is null, then you can have foreign key that's nullable.

Comment: I believe this is accurate for Rails 4 and below, is that correct?

Comment: @karns exactly.

Answer (score 200):

Note that **in Rails 5** and **in Rails 6** you may need to mark the corresponding association as optional if it's 1:n (`belongs_to`), as the default was changed:

`belongs_to :author, optional: true`

This is the corresponding [Changeset](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18233).

To use the old behavior across your application, you can also set:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

in `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb`

The error you will usually see is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Class must exist
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'
```

You may also need to update any migration: change `null: false` to true and run `rake db:redo` if it had already run.

Answer (score 21):

Adding `optional: true` along with `belongs_to :author` in `article` model will do the job.

Comment: This works only for mongoid... just ran into the same problem but using pg. Doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: The above line is directly taken from my app that runs on PG. I haven't faced any such problem while working on  Postgres.

Comment: Confirm @RajanVerma-Aarvy is correct; this worked for me on postgres db.