# Validation fails, field must exist with allow_nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm creating a blog where articles can be responses to other articles. Articles can also be part of groups. However articles do not have to be in a group or be a response to another article.

I'm attempting to follow the Rails docs to create articles as [self-joined records](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins).

I created user, group and article scaffolds:

```
bin/rails g scaffold user username:string email:string birthday:date

bin/rails g scaffold group name:string user:references

bin/rails g scaffold article user:references parent:references title:string subheading:string body:text pub_date:datetime group:references hidden:boolean prompt:boolean
```

I'm trying to use `allow_nil` in the model validation.

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Article"
  has_many :replies, class_name: "Article", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :group

  validates :parent, length: {minimum: 1}, allow_nil: true
  validates :group, length: {minimum: 1}, allow_nil: true
end
```

However when I run the db:seed:

```
user1 = User.create(username: "pete01",email: "pete01@gmail.com",
    birthday:"1980-01-30")

article1 = Article.create!(user:user1, parent:nil, title:"My First Article",
        subheading:"This is important", body:"The body of my first article",
        pub_date:"2015-12-26", group:nil, hidden:false, prompt:false)
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Parent must exist, Group must exist
```

Is there somewhere else where I should be telling Rails it does not need to validate Group and Parent?

Comment: what is your validation supposed to validate?

Comment: Ideally nothing. I'd like to turn off validation for parent and group.

Comment: Then remove your calls to validates

Comment: I get the same error without any calls to validates. I thought I had to pass `allow_nil` to turn off the validation.

Comment: Does `ApplicationRecord` add any validations? Please run `Article.validators` on the rails console and add the result to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Article"
   belongs_to :group

   validates :parent, presence: true, allow_nil: true
   validates :group, presence: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

Several problems for you:

You're validating `parent` & `group` -- these are associative *objects*.

Your error says `"[Object] must exist"`, which means your validation *works* -- Rails cannot find a "nil" association (it's expecting objects).

What you *should* have is either to validate `parent_id` & `group_id`, or to validate the presence of the associative object with something like `presence`.

I've included the following validations I would use:

```
validates :parent, presence: true, allow_nil: true
validates :group, presence: true, allow_nil: true
```

You could also try:

```
validates :parent_id, length: { minimum: 1 }, allow_nil: true
validates :group_id, length: { minimum: 1 }, allow_nil: true
```

---

> Articles can also be part of groups

You'll probably want to use a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association for it then:

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

You'll need a join table called `articles_groups` with the columns `article_id` & `group_id`:

[image]

You can create the migration as follows:

```
$ rails g migration CreateArticlesGroups

# db/migrate/create_articles_groups__________.rb
class CreateArticlesGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles_groups, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :article, index: true
      t.belongs_to :group, index: true
    end
  end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

This will allow you to populate the associative objects like this:

```
@article = Article.find params[:article_id]
@group = Group.find params[:id]

@article.groups << group
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between object and id, that was key.

Answer (score 7):

Solution is to find the file `new_framework_defaults.rb`, change this to `false`:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely to be the result of migrating to Rails 5, where the default for `belongs_to` relations changed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37803756/4494) for details,

Answer (score 1):

`allow_nil: true` is an option to a validator, not to the `validates` method. You are using the `length:` key which will call the `LengthValidator` with the `{minimum: 1}` hash as arguments (similar to using `validates_length_of`).

E.g., use

`validates :parent, length: {minimum: 1, allow_nil: true}`

instead of

`validates :parent, length: {minimum: 1}, allow_nil: true`

---

Note: If using multiple validators, you will need to specify `allow_nil` for each of them.

Comment: Both versions of `validates` give the same error message.

Comment: This is odd. I have been working with rails for a while now and I was pretty sure about this one. Did you apply the refactoring to both validation lines? Are you using zeus? (restart it!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your validations. Also check your migration for `Article`. Maybe you have `null: false` there for `group_id` and `parent_id`

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Article"
  has_many :replies, class_name: "Article", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: Removing the validations gives the same result. I checked the migrations and the schema, parent and group do not have `null: true`.