# Validation failed Class must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, model-associations, belongs-to

I have been (hours) trouble with associations in Rails. I found a lot of similar problems, but I couldn't apply for my case:

City's class:

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

User's class:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 80 }
  validates :city_id, presence: true
end
```

Users Controller:

```
def create
    Rails.logger.debug user_params.inspect
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save!
      flash[:success] = "Works!"
      redirect_to '/index'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
 end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :citys_id)
end
```

Users View:

```
<%= form_for(:user, url: '/user/new') do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :citys_id, "City" %>
  <select name="city">
    <% @city.all.each do |t| %>
      <option value="<%= t.id %>"><%= t.city %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
end
```

Migrate:

```
class CreateUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user do |t|
      t.string :name, limit: 80, null: false
      t.belongs_to :citys, null: false
      t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Message from console and browser:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: City must exist):
```

Well, the problem is, the attributes from User's model that aren't FK they are accept by User.save method, and the FK attributes like citys_id are not. Then it gives me error message in browser saying that "Validation failed City must exist".

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add nullable foreign key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589399/add-nullable-foreign-key)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Try the following:

```
belongs_to :city, optional: true
```

According to the [new docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#optional):

> 4.1.2.11 :optional
>
> If you set the :optional option to true, then the presence of the
> associated object won't be validated. **By default, this option is set
> to false.**

Comment: Hey Igor.. it's nice to see a BR here :) Thank you for your answer. It worked! I found this answer earlier, but I didn't have tried until now. The reason was that it seems to me this **option** invalidate the attributer's validation in a server level. So I checked to be sure, when I give a wrong value to the foreign key city_id the error message just show up after the DB tried to make a insertion query, it seems to me a DB level validation. Anyways, I will make my own validation in a server level to solve this. I would like to give you a UPVOTE, but I don't have enough score :( haha

Comment: ohhh, I didn't know that! hahaha nice :)

Comment: Argh this is quite an annoying gotcha. In `FactoryGirl`, if you simply make a factory for `User` without that snippet, in the `belongs_to` class, you will get that error. Good catch!

Answer (score 15):

This comes a bit late but this is **how to turn off this by default** in rails 5:

***config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb***

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

In case you don't want to add `optional: true` to all your `belongs_to`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I upgraded to Mac OS Mojave yesterday and now I'm getting these validation errors, even though my project has set this to false (since we upgraded to Rails 5 way back when). Anyone know what makes this happen?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the following to the end of the belongs_to relationship statement:

```
optional: true
```

It is possible to set this on a global level so that it works in the same way as older versions of rails, but I would recommend taking the time to manually add it to the relationships that really need it as this will cause less pain in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I found out a solution to the problem "Validation failed: Class must exist" and it's better than use:

```
belongs_to :city, optional: true
```

> 4.1.2.11 :optional
>
> If you set the :optional option to true, then the presence of the associated object won't be validated. By default, this option is set to false.

cause you still make a validation in application level. I solve the problem making my own validation in create method and changing user_params method:

```
def create

  @city = City.find(params[:city_id])

  Rails.logger.debug user_params.inspect
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  @user.city_id = @city.id

  if @user.save!
    flash[:success] = "Works!"
    redirect_to '/index'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name)
end
```

I didn't test this code, but it works in another project mine. I hope it can help others!

Answer (score 2):

**Rails 5**

If you have a `belongs_to` relationship to `:parent` then you have to pass an existing parent object or create a new one then assign to children object.

Comment: Can you provide example? As I would prefer not to use optional: true

Comment: I also need an example. Learning rails and I just can't find how would I do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
belongs_to :city, required: false
```

Comment: Please try to give an explanation to answer the question and not just post code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :citys_id)
```

It's a mistake, isn't it? (city**s**_id vs city_id)

Comment: yeah, it's. The values on the permit must match with the ones come from the views. You can see these values on your console after a submit.

Comment: Yours mistake helps me understand i have similar problem: I swapped two chars on the field name.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

This works because the Rails 5 has true by default
to disable you go under Initilizers then click on the New_frame-work and turn the true to false