# Rails 5 trouble with saving a nested fields_for .. error message <xxx> must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for, nested-form-for

I have the following models:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :interests, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :interests

  validates_presence_of  :email
  validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => %w(M F), message: "Gender can     only be in M or F"
  has_secure_password

  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def interests_concatenated
    interests.map { |i| i.interest }.join(", ")
  end
end

class Interest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
end
```

My controller is as follows:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

def index
  @person = Person.all
end

def new
  @person = Person.new
  @person.interests.build
end

def create
  @person = Person.new(people_params)
  if @person.save
    session[:user_id] = @person.id
    redirect_to(people_path)
  else
    flash = "Email or gender can't be blank!"
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def people_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :password,:password_confirmation, interests_attributes: [:hobby])
  end
end
```

My form is as follows:

```
<%= form_for @person  do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :email %> <br>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :first_name %> <br>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :last_name %> <br>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :gender %> <br>
  <%= f.label(:gender_male, "Male") %>
  <%= f.radio_button(:gender, "M") %> <br>
  <%= f.label(:gender_female, "Female") %>
  <%= f.radio_button(:gender, "F") %> <br>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :password %> <br>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %> <br>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.fields_for :interests do |i| %>
    <%= i.label :hobby %>
    <%= i.text_field :hobby  %>
  <% end %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Here is the byebug console log when I run it:

[image: console error message]

Very stumped why it's not working. Could it be something to do with the parameters?

Here is the log file when I submit the form:

[image]

Comment: have you tried `interests_attributes: [:hobby]` ?

Comment: Yes, actually it was interests_attributes: [:hobby] in the code, I don't know why it shows up at interests_attributes[:hobby] when I posted here

Comment: Instead of `@interests = @person.interests.new` try `@interests = @person.interests.build` ?

Comment: I just tried @person.interests.build and got the same error

Comment: Hmm, that's odd... Try adding `:person_id` to the `interests_attributes` permit/require line ? (note: shouldn't need to afaik)

Comment: @TarynEast I just tried that as well but still didn't work

Comment: :/ weird...  can you show us the relevant lines from the console output/logfiles after submitting? usually it'll say something like "Unpermitted parameters: blah blah blah" and sometimes the params that come through are really useful too... eg they show parameter-nesting errors that you otherwise miss...

Comment: @TarynEast I posted a screenshot of the byebug debugger, does that help?

Comment: Nah... the logs would really help us out a bit more here :)
You'll get them from either the terminal/console window, or from `logs/development.log` - just scroll to the end and then watch what gets output after you click "submit" (remove the `pry` for the short time while you're doing it)

Comment: @TarynEast ok, I just posted the development.log entry

Comment: Ok... and a couple of lines after that too, would be helpful - anything that occurs after you click the submit button. Also if you can - please post it as text, rather than an image, in case we need to copy/paste stuff from it :)
That said - at first glance it looks like ti's coming through ok... but we can't tell for sure until we see what it says when it tries to actually save the `person` object. Did you remove the `binding.pry` before running this (and getting the details from the log)?

Comment: Hi Taryn, that was actually all of the log that was printed. Sorry, I had to make it into an image file because when I tried to copy&paste the code, StackOverflow wasn't allowing me to post because it said my submission was" almost entirely code". I had removed binding.pry earlier. But I found a workaround solution down below. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution by adding this in my interests model:

```
class Interest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person, **optional: true**
end
```

Since @person fails to save each time, the biggest clue was in the error message "Interest person must exist", I found [this StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983666/validation-failed-class-must-exist) to be helpful. Also this [blog post on why this is needed](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html) was helpful in shedding light on the issue.

Thanks to everyone that weighed in on it!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
@interests = @person.interests.new
```

try

```
@interests = @person.interests.build
```

`new` creates a fresh, clean, completely empty new object... but `build` is the special Rails association method that will fill it with appropriate defaults (like, eg the right `person_id`)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I still get the same error