# Rails API - React: Site ID returns null on POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app has a Rails API back end and React front end.

The ERD only has three params: a User `has_many :sites`, a Site `belongs_to :user` and `has_many :pages`, and a Page `belongs_to :site`.

All the CRUD functions work except when I try to post a page that belongs to a site to my Active Records backend.

If I look at the Rails Console, I can see the sites & the user it belongs to:

```
#<Site:0x00007fbc9ad9fe28 id: 94, name: "Daffy", category: "test", user_id: 1, created_at: Tue, 15 Oct 2019 13:53:23 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 15 Oct 2019 13:53:23 UTC +00:00>]
```

however, when I try to post a page to the site, the site ID comes back nil

```
#<Page:0x00007fbc9b5069c8 id: 2, content: "\"\"", site_id: nil, created_at: Tue, 15 Oct 2019 10:51:42 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 15 Oct 2019 10:51:42 UTC +00:00>]
```

Looking at Chrome dev tools, I get error 422:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
:3000/users/1/sites/94/pages/:1
```

& in Network under the Preview tab, I get

```
{site: ["must exist"]}
site: ["must exist"]
```

I've taken a look at the following StackOverflow posts related to this:

[POST 422 (Unprocessable Entity) in Rails? Due to the routes or the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098239/post-422-unprocessable-entity-in-rails-due-to-the-routes-or-the-controller)

and

[Validation failed Class must exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983666/validation-failed-class-must-exist)

but neither worked for in my particular case.

SitesController.rb

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_site, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize_request, only: [:create]

...

  def create
    @site = Site.new(site_params)
    @current_user.sites << @site
      render json: @site, status: :created
  end

...

    def site_params
      params.require(:site).permit(:name, :category, :user_id)
    end
end
```

I've been going at this for a while, I'm hoping someone that knows Rails a lot better than I do can point out what I'm missing.

Comment: I may not understand completely what is going on, but dont you want a Site.create instead of a Site.new?  Site.new does not create an id until it is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `create` action. As `zakariah1` pointed out, `Site.new` will just initialize the `Site`, you need to save it in the database using `Site.create`.

Also, you don't need this code `@current_user.sites << @site` in your action. Since, your `site_params` have `user_id`, rails associations does that for you.

So here's how your controllers should look:

```
# sites_controller.rb
def create
  @site = Site.new(site_params)
  if @site.save
    render json: @site, status: :created
  else
    # render error
  end
end

...

def site_params
  params.require(:site).permit(:name, :category, :user_id)
end

# pages_controller.rb
def create
  @page = Page.new(page_params)
  if @page.save
    render json: @page, status: :created
  else
    # render error
  end
end

...

def page_params
  params.require(:page).permit(:name, :category, :site_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was correct except I did have to pass ```@current_user.sites << @site``` to make it work but I'm getting the ```site_id``` in my response.

Comment: @RHBlanchfield I think that's not a good practice to add, can you try this line `@site.user_id = @current_user.id` instead of `@current_user.sites << @site` and see if things work?